# Intermittent 403s for legit users

Tags: django

My django app raises 403s for some users (about one out of 500 users).  What is odd is that csrfmiddlewaretoken value differs from the 'CSRF_COOKIE' value.  Is there any reason why this would happen?

Also, I did pull the apache logs and they seem to be legit users trying to use my website.

Below is the request data:

```
WSGIRequest path:/
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: { u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'5sufVJePCxwMPxuaTbG6OWdTQPgw0UM1'], }>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '128',
'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'jnDkSuLBcvTol6R5J0XDXtEqWQBrORyG',
'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/etc/apache2/htdocs',
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-us',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_DNT': '1',
'HTTP_HOST': 'www.xxxx.com',
'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://www.xxxx.com',
'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.xxxx.com/',
'HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR': '107.170.206.62',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx, xx.xxxx.xxxx.xx',
'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx',
'PATH_INFO': u'/',
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an error, and not the CSRF protection working properly?

Comment: Good question.  One of my clients actually hit this trying to submit a payment form. When I looked up the logs, I noticed that this was happening quite a bit.